# Intriguing sql query (not in select)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql query in mysql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM _t_test
WHERE pret NOT 
IN ( 2.6700, 2.6560, 1.8200 )
```

I would expect the rows with the value 1.8200 not to be shown, yet I still get them.
Am I missing something?
The field "pret" is double(16,4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a rounding error. A double is not an exact value, so 1.8200 isn't represented exactly, so the values are not exactly the same.

For MYSQL floating points, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html

> The correct way to do floating-point number comparison is to first
>   decide on an acceptable tolerance for differences between the numbers
>   and then do the comparison against the tolerance value. For example,
>   if we agree that floating-point numbers should be regarded the same if
>   they are same within a precision of one in ten thousand (0.0001), the
>   comparison should be written to find differences larger than the
>   tolerance value

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Thank you, I got it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html